# Redux vs Hooks/Context API vs ApolloClient

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

Sorry if this feels more like a discussion topic than a SO question but am facing a conundrum.

What am trying to build:

So I have 2 webapps (A & B) that both import a component (The-Component) (from npm)

Webapp A has REDUX
Webapp B had GraphQL+Apollo

A little about The-Component:

- It will make a lot of API calls which are configured inside it
- It has its own state
- It has deeply nested component tree
- Its published to npm so Webapp A & B can use it

Both Webapp A & B should be able to drop the component in and with a few props passed, it should do the rest.

My question is what would be the best strategy to manage all of the internal state for The-Component?

Once again, am aware of the SO guidelines but would really love to see what people think/if they've worked on something similar

Comment: If The-Component is a separate package then you don't need to consider whether A or B use redux, graphql etc. The only thing they care about is passing The-Component props. I would use Apollo-Client if The-Component is making GQL calls, or redux (I like redux-starter-kit) with hooks. Redux does what context does but gives you a much richer experience. Maybe that's not needed though.